# Turning Multiple rows query result into one row when using entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, gridview

I have a query that returns the marks scored by students in a text.

```
     Dim subjectSearch = From subSearch In DemoSchool.EssenceSubjectRegistrations Where subSearch.Session = drpSession.SelectedItem.Text _
        AndAlso subSearch.RealClass.ClassSN = findClassSN.FirstOrDefault AndAlso _
                       subSearch.SubjectCode = drpSubject.SelectedValue _
                       Select New With {.SubjectRegSN = subSearch.SubjectRegSN,
                                       .FirstName = subSearch.Student.FirstName,
                                       .Surname = subSearch.Student.Surname,
                                        .CA1 = subSearch.CA1,

                                         .CA4 = subSearch.CA4 }
```

The above query returns a result like this when bounded to a gridview. Each student has a total of three records in the database.

```
    SubjectRegSN   FirstName  Surname  CA1  CA4
     101            James       Osa     45   65
     102            James       Osa     76   98
     103            James       Osa     56   76   
     105            Fames       Dan     45   65
     106            Fames       Dan     76   98
     107            Fames       Dan     56   76
```

but i want something of this nature

```
    SubjectRegSN   FirstName  Surname  CA1  CA4 CA1  CA4 CA1  CA4
        1           James      Osa     45    65  76   98  56  76
        2           Fames      Dan     45    65  76   98  56  76
```

The subjectSN is the primary key in the database of the table EssenseSubjectRegistration that am selecting from. Please help out.

Comment: I don't think you can have unknown count of "CA1  CA4 CA1  CA4 CA1  CA4" in the object :). You can have a collection of CA1 and CA4 by using grouping by FirstName and Surname.

Comment: @RomanBats please can you show me how to do it if it won't be a bother.